# How to generate java source using database details in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jpa-2.0, rcp, osgi-bundle, eclipse-jdt

I need a eclipse plugin which can generate a pojo with fields based on the columns of primary table and number of secondary data base.

I'm aware of AST provided by eclipse JDT plugin to generate class. I wanted to know if there is any api that can take, class name, package name, primary table, secondary table and generate a entity based on the column names.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need **Eclipse Dali** plugin. Take a look at these topics:

- [Creating a JPA entity](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/task_create_jpa_entity.htm#BABFBJBG)
- [Generating entities from tables](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks006.htm#BABBAGFI)